# WCF: how to start simple cmd command on remote machine

Tags: c#, wcf, cmd

So i have `WCF` server running on remote machine.
This server received simple string as argument and i want this argument to execute via `command line`.

This is the function on the server side that need to execute the `command`:

```
public void ExecuteCmdCommand(string arguments)
    {
        log.Info(arguments);
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        log.Debug(startInfo.Arguments);
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
        {                
            log.Info(args.Data);
        };

        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
```

As you can see at the beginning of this `function` i am print to my `console` the `command` that received.

So i try to start `notepad` by pass the argument `notepad`, i can see via the console that the command is received on the server side so i am can be sure that the communication works but nothing happened.

What i am doing wrong ? same command on my local machine start `notepad`.

**Update**

OK `notepad` work fine (also without `.exe` at the end) but when i am send the command `appium` (i want to start my `appium` server) i got this er`r`or when send the `command` to the `server` (but the `server` received 'appium' command):

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'The server was unable to process
>   the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the
>   error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from
>   ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration
>   behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information
>   back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.'

Comment: Is that service hosted in IIS? Or an windows service? Based on how those hosting processes are configure you might not "see" notepad as they are probably not enabled to have a display connected to them. if you send the arguments "/c dir c: > c:\temp\somedir.txt" (assuming c:\temp does exist and is writeable for everyone) can you find somedir.txt after you called the service?

Comment: Also hookup [ErrorDataReceived](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: add a try/catch in that server side code and log the error. Or enable WCF tracing on the server to have the exceptiondetails logged.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing

Comment: "the system cannot find the file specified" although appium is recognized when i try it manually

Comment: Your service doesn't have a proper PATH setting. Try using a fullpath. Remember that a service doesn't need to have the same settings in their profile or access to the same folders a user has. That you can run something means nothing for the service point of view.

Answer (score 1):

The FileName of the process is not correct, "cmd.exe". You could try this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(arguments);
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

and in the arguments pass the following:

```
notepad.exe
```

For a detailed overview of `ProcessStartInfo` class please have look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2).

I suggest you think about the case in which you want to pass in arguments also some arguments related with the process you want to start. For instance, you may want to start notepad and open a file. The file should be passed also as an argument. So I think that a rather better approach it would be to make `arguments` an array of strings and follow the convention that the first element of the array is the program you want to start and the rest elements of the array are program's arguments.

Comment: And i need to delete the rest ?

Comment: @falukky Essentially you don't need this `startInfo.Arguments = arguments`.